# Printing contents of a char array gives outofbound exception

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to get the mid, first & last character of a string. Here is what i've done. I'm not sure about what exactly need to be done.

```
import java.util.*;
class Test11{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String input=sc.nextLine();
    int length=input.length();
    int even_odd=length%2;
    if(even_odd==1){
        int mid=length/2;
        char mid_letter[]=input.toCharArray();
        int first=0; int last=length;
        System.out.println(mid_letter[mid]+mid_letter[first]+mid_letter[last]);
        }
    else System.out.println("Even String has no mid point. Try Again!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last variable needs to be

```
last = length-1
```

since java is '0 based'.

Comment: compiled, but didn't returned chars, instead 305.

Comment: You should be able to get rid of char mid_letter[] = input.toCharArray(); and just do what you're doing on input. input[mid]+input[first]+input[last].

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: well, my name! with a space.

Comment: doing this System.out.println(input[mid]+input[first]+input[last]); says expected array, found String.

Comment: Okay, so since you're adding the variables, its giving you the added ASCII values instead. S=83, e=101, y=121. 83+101+121=305. I believe this is what's happening

Comment: Return to what you had before and print like this System.out.println("%c %c %c", mid_letter[mid], mid_letter[first], mid_letter[last]